# Showing a user's Google calendar in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, google-calendar-api

I want for a user to be able to login to their google account, and for my website to be able to show their Calendar. The tutorial [here](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207) is for embedding an existing calendar.

I also tried following the [javascript quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js) for the calendar api, and I am able to login and it list's my calendar's entries, but I want to embed a user's google calendar where they login and it shows their calendar interface.

Answer (score 2):

Check this guide

https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js

Good Look!!!!

Comment: So I got the javascript working. I am interested in loading a calendar interface/ui with this api. Is that possible? Meaning I want to be able to show the calendar UI to the user.

Comment: The purpose of an API is that you, with the data that they provide you, can implement your own UI in the way that you display the information in the way that you think is most convenient. So I think the answer would be no or at least I don't know it.